# qt + oracle connecting problem

Tags: sql, oracle, qt

I'm trying to connect to my db in Oracle with the following code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtSql>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication myApp(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db;
    db.addDatabase("QOCI");
    db.setDatabaseName("RFV75");
    db.setUserName("RFVDB19");
    db.setPassword("RFVB19");
    db.setPort(1521);

    return myApp.exec();
}
```

but i get the following error:
**QSqlDatabase: QOCI driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC3 QODBC**

i'm using QT 4.6 and QT Creator 2.0
i set the .pro file to:

```
QT       += core gui sql
```

what's the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an Oracle driver compiled into your Qt libraries.

This might help: [QOCI for the Oracle Call Interface (OCI)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.0/sql-driver.html#qoci-for-the-oracle-call-interface-oci)

Comment: now that i have the plugin how i combine it with my program ?

Comment: If you've compiled it and installed it, it should be loaded automatically when needed. Have you looked at the 'Troubleshooting' section in the documentation at the link?

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't linked the Oracle driver to your executable.