# Connect to Oracle DB with Qt on Linux in C++

Tags: c++, linux, database, oracle, qt

i've already read the Oracle Doc for OCCI, but I've serious issues understanding the docs. I installed the Instant Client on my Linux Computer and tried the Setup with SQL*Plus and everything works fine. I am able to connect to the Oracle Database. I tried the Library SQLAPI++, but wasn't able to compile the Code. However, I try to use OCCI.

I haven't found a helpful tutorial yet. The Oracle Docs didn't help in understanding.

Now, how can I connect to the Database with Qt? I'm pretty lost and would appreciate an example or step by step guide.

I'm using
Qt Creator 4.9.0
Based on Qt 5.12.2
on Ubuntu 18.04

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: [Not an exact duplicate but this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646854/qt-oracle-connecting-problem)

Comment: You may find that the OCI API has more functionality than OCCI and has more examples.  There are also wrapper libraries for OCI like https://oracle.github.io/odpi/ (an example of this being called from C++ is https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/v3.1.2/src)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use the `cx_oracle` library:

https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/

or

QOCI

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qoci